# High Latency (2-4 seconds) bot response time using DirectLine SDK with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, botframework, direct-line-botframework

- SDK Platform: .NET
- SDK Version: 3.0.2
- Active Channels: Direct Line
- Deployment Environment: Azure Bot Service

we have created a Bot with LUIS which works fine with emulator for local and prod.
But, when we use DirectLine to connect with Bot from a Xamarin.forms mobile application. It takes about 4-5 seconds to create a conversation using 
this (`BotConversation = await Client.Conversations.StartConversationAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`)
line of code.

and when we try to send a message by creating a `Message` Type Activity it takes about 2-3 seconds.

```
Activity userMessage = new Activity()
        {
            From = new ChannelAccount(userId, userName),
            Text = message,
            Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
            Properties = new JObject(new JProperty("TenantCode", tenantCode),
                                     new JProperty("SiteCode", "1"))
        };

        await Client.Conversations.PostActivityAsync(BotConversation.ConversationId, userMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

can any one help or explain what is happening here ?

Comment: Where is your Bot Service Hosted and from where you are accessing the Bot?

Comment: it is hosted in Canada Central. Now i am going to deploy same in Central India. which is nearest to me.

Comment: @MandarDharmadhikari no improvements.

Comment: What is this bot using for the state service?

Comment: Its in-memory for maintaining state of chat.

Comment: You should be able to see dependency call duration times in Application Insights if you have configured it for the web application hosting the bot code.

Comment: ok, i will try and update you on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the reasons for high latency in response is:
1)Internet connection
2)The region you choose to host your bot in Azure

I don't think that your code causes that latency. I think the best solution is to change the region you deploy your bot in Azure.

Comment: Internet is pretty fast. I will try to change the bot region.

Comment: Ok, so I created an Echo bot from scratch without any code modification and tried that by initializing Conversation which took same amount of time as was the previous one. This bot does not have LUIS as well and azure region is Central India. And I am in the same city as of azure region.

Comment: Check this link,maybe it will help you:https://blog.botframework.com/2017/02/02/direct-line-performance-improvements/

Comment: already been here. and i checked it uses `directline.botframework.com` by default